# Getting different results on Manual Sorting of CSV[through MS-Excel] and Java Collections.sort() method

Tags: java, excel, sorting

I'm trying to compare a Baselive CSV file with a programatically downloaded CSV file for their contents. The downloaded CSV file is always in random order and hence I thought about sorting the Baselive CSV and also the downloaded CSV.

On the downloaded CSV, I'm using Collections[ ArrayList] to store each and using `Collections.sort(csvList, Collator.getInstance(Locale.US));` and adding the results back to a CSV and trying to compare.

The problem is, the 
`Collections.sort(csvList, Collator.getInstance(Locale.US));` 
will sort the lines in the below order:

> NOTE: the below items are only the 1st field of the csv

__text
_id
Business Description
Data Owner
0-6_population_female
Abbrev
Account__Number
ADDRESS1
ADDRESS2
age
AGE
answer_1
BAR
batter1

However manually performing the sort on the CSV will consider the following priority

1.special characters
2.Numbers
3.Letters in alphabetical order [irrespective of the case]

and hence my sorted items are 
__text
_id
0-6_population_female
Abbrev
Account__Number
ADDRESS1
ADDRESS2
age
AGE
answer_1
BAR
batter1
Business Description
Data Owner

> Why does the sorting through code give me the above output which is different from a manual sort.
>   How can I get the sorting right through my code, so that it will help me compare the downloaded csv with the baseline. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "will sort in a very wierd order" What do you mean? The example you've give is just a single line? If those are multiple lines then you've probably messed up the formatting and it  is really unclear what the output is.

Comment: I've made an edit. I've mentioned the sorted order throught manual sorting and using java Collections.sort().

Comment: Sorry but it is still unclear to me what the elements of the list are. Whitespace is the separator here? In your example of correctly sorted elements `BAR` is before Abbrev, why? What data structured do you use to store those elements in Java? What is `csvList`?

Comment: looks like you're going to nee to define a custom comparator that does things in the manner of the manual sort

Comment: @Amongalen The elements are the 1st Field in the csv. Updated the Manual sorted list.

Comment: One more question. Are you sure "Business Description" and "Data Owner" don't contain whitespaces at the beginning? By looking at your data only these two elements are out of place, other than that everything else is the same. So my guess there is something at the start, either it is a whitespace or some "hidden" character. When you're importing it to Excel it gets trimmed by default, which isn't the case in Java.